# Safely get nested list index from json?

Tags: python, json, list, key

I know how to safely get keys from json using `.get()`

```
data = {"person": {"name": "chris", "age": 11, "interests": []}}
```

`data.get("person", {}).get("height")` would just return `None`

But what if I wanted to do the same with a list?

`data.get("person", {}).get("interests", []).get([3], {}).get("someotherdata")`

How do I assume the list index exists and carry on safely if it doesn't?

Obviously I could just try getting the list and checking its length before trying to get the index, but is there not a cleaner way?

Chris

Comment: `.get()` only works with dictionaries. I don't think there's anything equivalent for lists.

Comment: You can easily write a `list_get()` function that does what you want.

Comment: I don't agree with the dupe because its not applicable to method chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`match-case`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/):

```
data = {"person": {"name": "chris", "age": 11, "interests": []}}
match data:
   case {"person": {"interests": [_, _, _, val, *_]}}:
      print(val)
   case _: #default case, only executes no match is made
      pass
```

Here, the `case` block attempts to match a nested dictionary containing the keys `"person"` and `"interests"`, and then provides a match if the `"interests"` key has a corresponding list with an index of three.

In the example above, nothing will be printed, since the list value for `"interests"` is empty. However, if `"interests"` has an index of `3`, `4` will be printed:

```
data = {"person": {"name": "chris", "age": 11, "interests": [1, 2, 3, 4]}}
match data:
  case {"person": {"interests": [_, _, _, val, *_]}}:
     print(val)
  case _:
     pass
```

Output:

```
4
```

Edit: purely inline solution:

```
r = v[3] if len(v:=data.get('person', {}).get('interests', [])) > 3 else {}
```

Comment: excellent answer! maybe provide a default case for the match statement, to emulate `get`.

Comment: @timgeb Thank you, good suggestion, please see my recent edit.

Comment: That is a good answer but not what I was after. I was after something more "inline" and simpler than getting the list, checking if its valid, then getting the index.

Comment: @Chris Please see my recent edit, I added an inline solution which will produce either the third element of the list if available, and an empty dictionary if it is not.